# Dynamic UPDATE statement to update values in columns returned by a previous SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, hsqldb

In essence, what I want to do is:

- find all tables and their columns that match a specific query,
- update values in these columns.

So say I have something like

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE
    (
      TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC'
    ) AND (
      COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHING%'
      OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHINGELSE%'
    ) AND (
      DATA_TYPE = 'BIGINT' OR
      DATA_TYPE = 'TINYINT' OR
      DATA_TYPE = 'SMALLINT' OR
      DATA_TYPE = 'INTEGER'
    )
```

Or for Oracle something like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
  FROM USER_TAB_COLS
  WHERE
    (
      COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHING%'
      OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHINGELSE%'
    ) AND
    DATA_TYPE IN ('NUMBER')
```

I want to then do an `UPDATE` on all resulting columns similar to:

```
UPDATE _RESULTING_COLUMN_NAMES_HERE_THEORETICALLY_
  SET
    _SINGLE_COLUMN_NAME_ = _SOME_NEW_VALUE_
  WHERE _SINGLE_COLUMN_NAME_ = _SOME_OLD_VALUE_;
```

Well obviously that does not work or even exist, but I hope you understand what I want to achieve.

I could see a way where you generate an `UPDATE` statement for each matching table from the `SELECT` resultset, but I don't really see how to achieve this.

To make things more fun, I'd need to do that for a list of old_value to new_value transformations.

Any ideas are welcome.

I am trying to have this work on HSQLDB and Oracle as my 2 requirements, but supporting additional platforms would be a pretty good bonus.

Comment: the select query you posted is related to MSSQL Not oracle?

Comment: @Tarun: not that should work fine on Oracle (though I don't have an Oracle intance fired up just yet where I am to check). Works fine on HSQLDB. Haven't tried on MSSSQL and not interested.

Comment: did u run that select query in oracle db? is it working fine?

Comment: @Tarun: Like I said, I can't at the moment. I assumed Oracle supported the INFORMATION_SCHEMA standard as I had seen it in some docs. My local environment is HSQLDB, but my target env is Oracle, which I don't have access to to work.

Comment: @Tarun: those docs were for MySQL... Kinda slipped my mind that they might be hosted on oracle.com now...

Comment: @Tarun: question updated with sort of equivalent Oracle query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you think you **need** to use dynamic SQL, you should stop, take a step back and see if there's another way to do it, or if you REALLY need to do what you're doing .

I'd probably seriously question your base "requirement" of:

- updating all columns for all tables matching some string, and of type integer (or variations thereof).

Something still smells "funny" ... I'd be VERY careful about what you're doing - make sure you know what the results are going to be, test test test .. and TEST again ... on a DEV box somewhere ...

that said, anytime I need to resort to dynamic SQL, I have found the simplest way is to start with a "template":

So in your case, the final UPDATE you want to fire is as you put it:

```
  UPDATE _RESULTING_COLUMN_NAMES_HERE_THEORETICALLY_
    SET
      _SINGLE_COLUMN_NAME_ = _SOME_NEW_VALUE_
    WHERE _SINGLE_COLUMN_NAME_ = _SOME_OLD_VALUE_;
```

Ok, I'd probably re-write that as a string now, and start a query using the WITH clause:

```
  WITH w_template AS ( select 
        rtrim(q'[ UPDATE _RESULTING_COLUMN_NAMES_HERE_THEORETICALLY_    ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[   SET                                                 ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[     _SINGLE_COLUMN_NAME_ = _SOME_NEW_VALUE_           ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[   WHERE _SINGLE_COLUMN_NAME_ = _SOME_OLD_VALUE_;      ]')
           template from dual
        )
```

Note I haven't changed anything in your query (yet). All I did was wrap some `"q'["` and `"]'"` around it ... an `rtrim`, a `CHR(10)` and put it in a `WITH` clause.

1) `q'[ some string ]'`   is an alternate way to do a string. The advantage of it is you can have single quotes inside that string without any real issue:
ie   `q'[ some 'string' ]'`   works just fine ... prints `" some 'string' "`

2) `RTRIM` - I left spaces at end of line in there as cosmetic so it's easier for us to read. However, due to length restrictions of strings, those spaces can grow that string really big, really fast with a larger query. So `RTRIM` is a habit I've gotten into .  Keep the cosmetic spaces, but tell Oracle not to use them ;)  they're just for us.

3) `CHR(10)` - cosmetic only - you can leave this off if you want. I like it as if you want to dump the query during testing, you can easily read the query and see what it built.

Next we'll change the names of your dynamic values there so we can more easily spot them and substitue them:

```
  WITH w_template AS ( select 
        rtrim(q'[ UPDATE <table_name>                   ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[   SET                                 ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[     <col_name> = <col_new_val>        ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[   WHERE <col_name> = <col_old_val>;   ]')
           template from dual
        )
```

all I did was create an easily identified "strings" that I'll use to substitute values in later.

**Note** that if your columns were strings, you might need quotes in there: `<col_name> = '<col_new_val>'`
but seems you're dealing with integer data .. so I think we're ok ...

Now we need to pull your data ... so we go back to your original query:

```
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
          FROM USER_TAB_COLS
          WHERE
            (
              COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHING%'
              OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHINGELSE%'
            ) AND
            DATA_TYPE IN ('NUMBER')
```

Hmm, I'll have to trust you in your query there, I'm not sure that'll run on Oracle, but you know your query better than I do ;) So I'll trust your query "as is" for this example - as long as it picks out the data you want, and includes the table name, column name, and the before/after values you want (which it currently doesn't) we're ok.

So all we need to do is tack those two together ... we'll do this:

```
  WITH w_template AS ( select 
        rtrim(q'[ UPDATE <table_name>                   ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[   SET                                 ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[     <col_name> = <col_new_val>        ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[   WHERE <col_name> = <col_old_val>;   ]')
           template from dual
        )
     w_data AS (
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
          FROM USER_TAB_COLS
          WHERE
            (
              COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHING%'
              OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHINGELSE%'
            ) AND
            DATA_TYPE IN ('NUMBER')
        )
```

Then we just need to add the final query, using REPLACE to substitute values ..

(note: not sure where you get "some_new_value" and "some_old_value" from ??? you'll have to join that into your query .. )

```
  WITH w_template AS ( select 
        rtrim(q'[ UPDATE <table_name>                   ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[   SET                                 ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[     <col_name> = <col_new_val>        ]')||CHR(10)||
        rtrim(q'[   WHERE <col_name> = <col_old_val>;   ]')
           template from dual
        ),
     w_data AS (
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
          FROM USER_TAB_COLS
          WHERE
            (
              COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHING%'
              OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHINGELSE%'
            ) AND
            DATA_TYPE IN ('NUMBER')
        )
  SELECT REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( 
              wt.template, '<table_name>', 
                             wd.table_name ),
                 '<col_name>', wd.column_name ),
                 '<col_new_val>', ??? ),
                 '<col_old_val>', ??? )  query
    FROM w_template wt,
         w_data wd
```

I left ??? there for the old / new values, since you didn't indicate where they'd come from ?? 
but if you run that, it *should* spit out some update statements .. ;)

Once you're comfortable with those, pushing them through execute immediate is the easy work.

Again, I would advise to be cautious of this approach, this is ok for a 1 off migration, or such, however, it is not advised for a daily job to be running on a regular basis.  ;)

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the very detailed answer. It's very interesting. My requirement is indeed smelling very funny, but it's not like I don't have a reason for it. You're right to question it though. I'll give some details...

Comment: In this case, it comes from the need to migrate a large database for an in-house product's next version, where some magic numbers are encoded within number columns (and more specifically, in the middle of these numbers, e.g. let's say on bits 5 to 16 or something like that, but that's another topic :). And for the next version of that product, some of these magic numbers have changed.

Comment: For extra fun, some of these columns are in varchar/string type, but that's a simple matter of doing a char to num conversion prior to computing the change and then re-converting. Yeah, it's pretty screwed up, but that's what I have to work with.

Comment: Ok, I finished reading through everything. That seems indeed close to what I want. And it's indeed pretty much for a one-off migration script. And considering it'd be for a 30GB DB with about 4800 matching column names where I'll be looking for those damn entries, I indeed wouldn't want to run it regularly. But as it's an issue we might have with other users of that product, I'm trying to do it right (it's rather rare edge case that should not have happened actually, where someone used internal magic numbers they were NOT allowed to use).

Comment: @haylem ... yeah, magic numbers, aren't ... O.o    Good luck!

Comment: My only concern now is that I think your script is very much "Oracle"-oriented, and I have very limited access to my target Oracle DB for pre-production or production. Hence the need to replicate on an HSQLDB first, which is used for development. But thanks a lot already for the gigantic help!

Comment: yeah, some of the syntax is Oracle specific, however, the logic is there, you could try altering the string concatenation to better suit HSQLDB or such .. not sure if it takes the WITH clause or not (I think it's ANSI standard now, isn't it ? could be wrong there :) )

Comment: Regarding the old_value and new_value stuff, they're pretty much a hard-coded list of translations that I don't have in the DB itself. So I guess I could either union with a table I create manually, or I could just then unrol the values using another script on top of that...

Comment: really not a DB expert, but I think the WITH clause probably is in another form for other DBs like MySQL or HSQLDB (probably simply a temporary named table, not too worried). It's more the `template from dual` that makes me think it's not as ubiquitous. I'll give it a shot and let you know tomorrow what I came up with. Thanks again.

Comment: Duuude - if I may call you that way - you are a **regular genious!!** This works beautifully. I'm still miles away from the complete resolution of my problem as there are quite a few other tricks and hurdles to wiggle with, but you took it quite a step closer and taught me a lot. Best answer I got on SO in a while. Tried it out with this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5f413449bc840a5db6a and it nicely and dutifuly produces thousands of update statements like: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/270f4abf8f030cbe7660. Still need lots of extra conditionals for my use-case, but *great*!

Comment: @haylem : Glad I could help .. ;)  enjoy, and as always, be careful with those dynamic sqls .. :P  lol

Comment: now the next question is "what's going to be the impact of running thousands of those generated update queries, with some bit-fiddling / string conversion and math stuff on top?". But I'm confident I'll like the final trade-off.

Comment: Sorry bother you again, but would you have an idea why this fails: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f14d0a8d694162f830b2. I get this: `ERROR: ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 38

Error Code: 911

Query = <whole expression here>`. My understanding is the generated SQL contans an invalid char, but I can't figure out what it is, and I can execute it fine if I copy the select output to text and then paste it to execute manually.

Comment: @haylem: remove the semi-colon :  ";" ... don't pass a semi-colon into Execute immediate. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> find all tables and their columns that match a specific query,
>     update values in these columns.

With HSQLDB, it is not possible to do this with just SQL. You need to write a short Java program to list the required table names and their column names, then construct an UPDATE statement per table and execute it.

With Oracle, you could write the same program in PL/SQL. But the Java language solution is compatible with both database engines.

Comment: well the finding all tables part is definitely doable as I did it above. Indeed for the update bit it seems quite convoluted, though I'm pretty sure there must also be a way. But I was also looking into scripting it with Java or Groovy to execute the requests as well. I don't really like the idea of coming up with a cross-language solution though, as it will drive maintenance complexity and costs up for the people I'll deliver it to.